# Running Drupal 7 with URL-based Session Management?

Tags: session, drupal-7

Due to client requirements, I am faced with developing a Drupal 7 site that cannot use cookies for session management.

Several old threads on help sites suggest simply setting the relevant PHP configuration in the site's settings.php:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '0');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '1');
```

However, while this may have worked 11 years ago, it does not work now.

A quick look at the core session.inc file reveals why: the entirety of Drupal's session handling is written assuming that cookies will be available.

However, it is possible to override the session handler used by supplying the path to the new handler in the `session_inc` variable.

So I *could* solve this by writing a new version of session.inc and loading it up instead of the other one, but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

I can't find any recent mention of the topic, but if someone could suggest any resources, or some pointers on how to go about rewriting session.inc, I'd be glad to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

So, three things are needed to implement this:

Entries in your `settings.php` file:

```
$conf['session_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/custom/my/session.inc';

ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '0');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '1');
```

Make your modified version of `session.inc`. The main thing is to use `$_GET` in place of `$_COOKIES`. (I ended up stripping out all of the extra security used by HTTPS, to make life easier for the other party.)

Put a `hook_drupal_goto_alter` in your module:

```
function my_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
    if (ini_get('session.use_trans_sid')) {
        if (!isset($options['query'])) $options['query'] = array();

        $options['query'][session_name()] = session_id();
    }
}
```

For those who are worried about the security aspect: this rather insecure mechanism will only ever be accessed from one specific server. That server will have a HOSTS entry to an otherwise-unbound subdomain, and that subdomain will have its own settings.php file. Anyone accessing the site via the normal domain will get the normal Drupal session treatment; anyone accessing the subdomain from the wrong IP address will be blocked.